# Product space between circle and disk

Tags: general-topology

What is the product space between the unit circle in the complex plane and the unit disk in the complex plane?

Isn't it a torus? That would be my intuitive answer if you would say the product space between the unit circle and the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but there is no three dimensional complex space is there?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

The product of two circles is a torus: $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ (embedded in 4-dimensional space).

The product of a circle and a disk is a *solid* torus (embedded in 4-dimensional space). The torus $T^2$ is this solid torus' surface.

Comment: Thanks! A solid torus was also what I meant.

Comment: I figured as much. Language is typically used loosely in that way. When someone says "circle" or "sphere" or "triangle", usually context is needed to figure out if they mean the edge of the thing or the edge and everything inside. :)